Google Cloud Run and Identity Aware Proxy
My main goal is to deploy a R Shiny app on GCP and make it subject to authorization so that only certain users can access it.
To start simple, I am not trying to deploy my docker container with my Shiny app, but rather I am trying to deploy the GCP demo container, called 'hello'.
I am following this post (https://hodo.dev/posts/post-30-gcp-cloudrun-iap/), as suggested in here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70533626), with a slight modification for what regards the SSL certificate. I am going to describe all steps I am taking anyway.


Log in to the project

gcloud auth login
gcloud auth list
gcloud projects list
gcloud config set project `PROJECT ID`
gcloud config configurations list




Deploy the demo container


In GCP console, from within my project, click CREATE SERVICE
In Container image URL, select Demo containers -> hello, then click SELECT
Service name: cloud-run-iap
Leave region on us-central1
Authentication: Require authentication
Ingress control: select Internal and tick the box 'Allow traffic from external application load balancers'
Leave the container port as default 8080
Then, click CREATE




Set project and region environment variables

PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config list project --format='value(core.project)')
REGION=us-central1




Configure IAP

Configure the OAuth consent screen

Go to the OAuth consent screen in the “APIs & Services” section
Choose “External” and then hit “Create”
Under Support email, select the email address you want to display as a public contact. This email address must be your email address, or a Google Group you own.
Enter the Application name you want to display.
Click Save.
Navigate again to the OAuth consent screen and add your user to the list of the test users.

Configure OAuth credentials

Go to the Credentials page in the “APIs & Services” section

On the Create credentials drop-down list, select *OAuth client ID.

Under Application type, select Web application.

Add a Name for your OAuth client ID.

Click Create. Your OAuth client ID and client secret are generated and displayed on the OAuth client window.

Click OK.

Select the client that you created.

Copy the client ID to the clipboard.

Add the universal redirect URL to the authorized redirect URIs field in the following format:
https://iap.googleapis.com/v1/oauth/clientIds/CLIENT_ID:handleRedirect

Then, store CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET to be used in the following commands.





Configure Load Balancer

Create the Network Endpoint Group (NEG)
gcloud compute network-endpoint-groups create cloud-run-iap-neg \
    --project $PROJECT_ID \
    --region=$REGION \
    --network-endpoint-type=serverless  \
    --cloud-run-service=cloud-run-iap

Create the backend service
gcloud compute backend-services create cloud-run-iap-backend \
    --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL \
    --global \
    --iap=enabled,oauth2-client-id=$CLIENT_ID,oauth2-client-secret=$CLIENT_SECRET

Add the serverless NEG as a backend to the backend service
gcloud compute backend-services add-backend cloud-run-iap-backend \
    --global \
    --network-endpoint-group=cloud-run-iap-neg \
    --network-endpoint-group-region=$REGION

Create the url map
gcloud compute url-maps create cloud-run-iap-url-map \
  --default-service cloud-run-iap-backend




Reserve an IP address

gcloud compute addresses create cloud-run-iap-ip \
    --network-tier=PREMIUM \
    --ip-version=IPV4 \
    --global

Then, copy the ip address to clipboard.
Next, update my DNS records creating an A record having this ip address as its value.
Store the domain name as environment variable:
DOMAIN_ADDRESS=my-domain-address.com




Add a Google Managed Certificate


Go to Certificate Manager API (enable it if not yet enabled)
Go to Classic Certificates https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs
Add Certificate
Give it a name (e.g. mysslcert)
Select ‘Create Google-managed certificate’
Hit CREATE

Store the certificate name to use it in the following commands:
CERTIFICATE_NAME=mysslcert

Create the https proxy
gcloud compute target-https-proxies create cloud-run-iap-http-proxy \
    --ssl-certificates $CERTIFICATE_NAME \
    --url-map cloud-run-iap-url-map

Create the global forwarding rule
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create cloud-run-iap-forwarding-rule \
    --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL \
    --network-tier=PREMIUM \
    --address=cloud-run-iap-ip \
    --global \
    --ports 443 \
    --target-https-proxy cloud-run-iap-http-proxy


At this point, if I navigate to the domain, I am asked to login and then I get this error page as described in the original tutorial, suggesting that the IAP is working.
SEE ERROR PAGE HERE


Grant the role IAP-secured Web App User

BACKEND_SERVICE=$(gcloud compute backend-services list --filter="name~'cloud-run-iap-backend'" --format="value(name)")
USER_EMAIL=$(gcloud config list account --format "value(core.account)")

gcloud iap web add-iam-policy-binding \
    --resource-type=backend-services \
    --service $BACKEND_SERVICE \
    --member=user:$USER_EMAIL \
    --role='roles/iap.httpsResourceAccessor'


Now, if I go to the domain, I get this error:

The IAP service account is not provisioned. Please follow the
instructions to create service account and rectify IAP and Cloud Run
setup: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run

Therefore, as per troubleshoot instructions at https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run I add:
gcloud beta services identity create --service=iap.googleapis.com --project=[PROJECT_ID]

But then if I go again to the domain I get:

Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get
URL / from this server.


I am stuck at this point and I do not understand what I am missing.
